# Python For loop to select row with earliest timestamp?

Tags: python

I'm creating a function to get the first value in a table based on the earliest timestamp but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is my fake data:

```py
 data = pd.DataFrame({"a": [None, np.NaN, np.NAN, "", "hello", 0],
                            "timestamp": [
                                datetime(2023, 10, 20, 8, 22, 2),
                                datetime(2023, 10, 21, 10, 25, 3),
                                datetime(2023, 10, 20, 6, 21, 21),
                                datetime(2023, 10, 19, 6, 22, 2),
                                datetime(2023, 10, 19, 6, 25, 8),
                                datetime(2023, 10, 19, 6, 21, 21)]})
```

My code:

```py
def get_first_value(df: pd.DataFrame, column_name: str, allow_null: bool = True
     try:
         column = df[column_name]
     except KeyError:
         return None
 
     for value in column.values:
         is_null = pd.isnull(value) or value == ""
         first_timestamp = min(df["timestamp"])
         final_value = None if is_null else value
         if allow_null or not is_null:
             if df["timestamp"] == first_timestamp is True:
             return first_value
 
     return None
```

This is throwing errors, specifically:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
```

I feel like it's very simple but I can't figure it out.

I've tried adding `if first_timestamp` in place as well but that didn't solve it. I'm hoping to have the output as:

| a |
| --- |
| 0 |

Comment: why write functions- google pandas methods?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this, without using a for loop:

1. Sort and take lowest

```
data.sort_values(['timestamp']).iloc[0]
```

2. Using `pd.min()`

```
data['timestamp'].min()
```

In your code, the error is coming from `df["timestamp"] == first_timestamp is True` which is an incorrect usage as you're comparing a series to a single value

To edit your func, you don't need a for loop, just pass in different data-frames and columns:

```
def get_first_value(df: pd.DataFrame, column_name: str):
  return df['column'].min(skipna=True)

min1 = get_first_value(df1, col_name1)
min2 = get_first_value(df2, col_name2)
....
```

--------UPDATED as per comments-------

You can use `argmin` to get the index of smallest timestamp, and then use that to get the corresponding "a" value

```
def get_first_value(df: pd.DataFrame, column_name: str, skipna = True, col_name2 = 'a'):
  idx = data['timestamp'].argmin(skipna=skipna)
  return data.iloc[idx][col_name2]

min1 = get_first_value(df1, col_name1)
min2 = get_first_value(df2, col_name2)
....
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll be using this function to sort through a lot of different datasets so I figured a for loop would be best? Is there a way to add what you shared to my for loop?

Comment: edit your function, just pass in all your data frames and column names to the function

Comment: Thank you! How will that work if I want to be able to later determine if I accept nulls or not? As of now the function is set to allow nulls but if I choose to set it as False later, how will I account for that without a for loop?

Comment: edit the function definition and pass `skipna` as a variable, but if you don't skip nans, most likely only nans will be returned as the min because of how they are treated as a datatype

Comment: Finding the minimum is O(N) whereas sorting is O(N log N). So if all you need is the minimum: just get the minimum, there's no need to pay the time cost of sorting.

Comment: Just edited the question as I realized my desired output was wrong and I'd only like the value based on the earliest timestamp. Basically, I'd like to replicate SQL's ``` select name, CASE WHEN name is NULL THEN NONE else name from table  group by 1, 2 having min(timestamp)```. I've tried the above solutions and it didn't work given the different data types I may have in my data. It is a requirement for the problem I'm eventually going to solve that I use a for loop. Any tips?

Comment: so you just want column "a" value for the minimum "timestamp"? @TullyTweety

Comment: Yes! Just the value from column "a".

Comment: You just need to use `argmin` then, updated the answer for that